# Unable to collect $_POST values from AJAX-generated dynamical form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an HTML-form that is partially produced in PHP and partially in AJAX (which I am new to), and I have gotten the script to work as intended, and I can collect the PHP-produced scripts, but not the AJAX-produced ones. Here's the form:

--EDIT: Changed position of the script and renamed "id" to "name" on affected POST's, but to no avail.

**index.jquery.php**

```
echo "      <form method='POST'>"; //Här börjar formuläret man fyller i.
echo "          <p>S&auml;llskapets namn: <input type='text' name='groupname' class='required'/></p>";
echo "          <p>Antal deltagare: <select name='participantsAmount' id='participantsAmount' data-mini='true'>"; //Nu börjar dropdown-listan över antal deltagare
echo "              <option value='0'>V&auml;lj antal</option>";
for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++)
{
    echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
}
echo "          </select>";
echo "          <div id='participants_added'>"; //I det här området skrivs alla deltagar-entryn ut från AJAX-koden nedan

echo "          </div>";
echo "  </form>";


if(isset($_POST['submitform']))
{
    $groupname = $_POST['groupname'];
    $misc = $_POST['misc'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $participants = $_POST['participantsAmount'];

    for($i = 0; $i < $participants; $i++)
    {
        $participant_name = $_POST['participant_name['.$i.']'];
        $participant_age = $_POST['participant_age['.$i.']'];
        $allergies = $_POST['allergies['.$i.']'];
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO submits (name, allergies, misc, age, email, groupname) VALUES ('$participant_name', '$allergies', '$misc', '$participant_age', '$email', '$groupname')")or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
<script>
var html = ''; //Allting som hamnar i den här variabeln skrivs ut i slutet av skriptet.
$(document).on('change', '#participantsAmount', function() { //AJAX-delen som lägger till deltagar-rutorna (namn1, ålder. namn2, ålder etc.)
    participants = $(this).val();
    html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < participants; i++) {
            var j = i + 1;
            html += '<fieldset class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><label for="participant_name['+i+']">Namn ' + j + '</label><input type="text" name="participant_name['+i+']" placeholder="Namn"/></div>';
            html += '<div class="ui-block-b"><label for="participant_age['+i+']">&Aring;lder</label><input type="text" name="participant_age['+i+']" placeholder="&Aring;lder" /></div>';
            html += '</fieldset>';
            html += '<p><label for="allergies['+i+']">Matrestriktioner/F&ouml;do&auml;mnesallergier</label><input type="text" name="allergies['+1+']" placeholder="Allergier" /></p>';
    }
    html += '<p><label for="misc">&Ouml;vrigt</label><textarea name="misc" id="misc"></textarea></p>';
    html += '<p><label for="email">E-postadress</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required email" placeholder="E-postadress" /></p>';
    html += '<p><input type="submit" name="submitform" value="Skicka anm&auml;lan" /></p>';
    $('#participants_added').html(html);
    //$('#participantsAdded').append('<input type="submit" value="Submit" />');
    $('.ui-page').trigger('create');
});
</script>
```

As stated earlier, I am able to collect and store the email, groupname and misc POST's, but not any of the other ones. As far as I know, I need the AJAX-script for the event listener function, otherwise I would probably have left that one out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Obviously you need to turn `error_reporting(-1)` I don't understand developers who <i>develop</i> with error reporting off. It blows my mind.

Comment: My bad, looked at an old error-log. Yea, there were index errors on those inside the loop, but I've got all except for one covered now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple: You forgot to add `name` attributes for the form fields in your loop:

```
<input type="text" id="participant_name['+i+']" placeholder="Namn"/>
```

should be:

```
<input type="text" name="participant_name['+i+']" placeholder="Namn"/>
```

etc.

I don't think you can use stuff like `id="participant_name['+i+']"` as the `[` and `]` characters are not [allowed in an id](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

Apart from that, your approach seems a bit strange, the whole javascript section is placed in the `div` that you overwrite with the results of that javascript. I would place the javascript somewhere else to avoid potential problems although I have never actually tried this...

Comment: I feel as it should have worked, but unfortunately it doesn't. Oh yea, I updated the question with new structure